# How i can do a gmap v3 with a multiples markers and these are draggable

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3

```
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: tittle,
    zIndex: i,
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    $("input[name='request']").val(marker.getPosition());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    $("input[name='request']").val(marker.getPosition());
});
```

the event is added to a single marker and need to be for many at least 1000 or even infinite.

Comment: Enclose your code in a `for()` loop, that should be all.

Answer (score 1):

use array of positions and for each position call addMarker method.

```
var locationsArray;

for(var i = 0 ; i<locationsArray.length; i++){
    addMarker(locationsArray[i]);
}


function addMarker(myLatLng){
var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
    position: myLatLng,
    map: map,
    icon: image,
    title: tittle,
    zIndex: i,
    draggable: true
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'drag', function() {
    $("input[name='request']").val(marker.getPosition());
});

google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'dragend', function() {
    $("input[name='request']").val(marker.getPosition());
});
}
```

Comment: I solved the issue for those who want in the future, my code was obviously enclosed in a for, and get the coordinates from the json ... the solution is to change within the event marker dragend "marker" by "this" ... regards, like this :

  google.maps.event.addListener(marker,'dragend', function() {

                                               $("input[name='request']").val(this.getPosition());

                                             });